# Mnesia - Replicate ram_copy table to disc_only_copy table from another node

Tags: erlang, mnesia, distributed-system

What I want to do is this:

Create a table ram_copies in node A which resides in a computer with lot of Ram and CPU power

```
mnesia:create_table(person, [{ram_copies, [node()]},
                        {frag_properties, [{node_pool, [node()]}, {n_fragments, 10}, {n_ram_copies, 1}]},
                        {attributes, record_info(fields, person)},
                        {storage_properties, [{ets, [compressed, {write_concurrency,true}, {read_concurrency,true}]}]}])
```

And node A starts working this ram_copy table.

At some unspecified time (which may be 1 second or 1 hour) after the node "A" have created the table, create node B on a computer with lots of hard drive, but less RAM and CPU power , to replicate (structure and data) RAM table in the "a" node but disc_only_copies.

The idea is to run critical processes using all the power at node A, and run trivial processes on another node and keep the data synchronized.

Is this possible?

Greetings.

Comment: How much RAM on the second node? disc_only_copies is limited to 2GB of content, which seems easy to imagine having.

Comment: Hello, the first node can have something like 64 GB RAM and 8 GB in SSD, but the second node can have 8 GB of RAM and 1TB in HDD. I know about the limit size of disc_only_copies, but to my knowledge, you can play with fragmentation to distribute data in the fragments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Let's say we have two nodes; `node_1` which has lots of *Disc* and `node_2` which has lots of *RAM*, and we have a `foo` table which must be `disc_only_copies` in `node_1` and `ram_copies` in `node_2`. The steps are as follows:

**Node 1:**

```
$ erl -sname node_1
(node_1@host)1> mnesia:create_schema([node()]). 
(node_1@host)2> mnesia:start(). 
(node_1@host)3> mnesia:add_table_copy(schema, node_2@host, ram_copies).
```

**Node 2:**

```
$ erl -sname node_2
(node_2@host)1> mnesia:start().
(node_2@host)2> mnesia:change_config(extra_db_nodes, [node_1@host]).
```

That's it. Now we can create `foo` table in `node_1`:

**Node 1:**

```
(node_1@host)4> mnesia:create_table(foo, [
                    {disc_only_copies, [node_1@host]}, 
                    {ram_copies, [node_2@host]}]).
```

Finally we can check if it is created on both nodes with `mnesia:info/0`:

**Node 1:**

```
running db nodes   = [node_2@host,node_1@host]
stopped db nodes   = [] 
master node tables = []
remote             = []
ram_copies         = []
disc_copies        = [schema]
disc_only_copies   = [foo]
[{node_1@host,disc_copies},{node_2@host,ram_copies}] = [schema]
[{node_1@host,disc_only_copies},{node_2@host,ram_copies}] = [foo]
```

**Node 2:**

```
running db nodes   = [node_1@host,node_2@host]
stopped db nodes   = [] 
master node tables = []
remote             = []
ram_copies         = [foo,schema]
disc_copies        = []
disc_only_copies   = []
[{node_1@host,disc_copies},{node_2@host,ram_copies}] = [schema]
[{node_1@host,disc_only_copies},{node_2@host,ram_copies}] = [foo]
```